# How to load a list from a file in DBT?

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

Suppose we want to have a long list of fruits to use in some queries:

```
apple
banana
... # more 100
melon
```

We want to use this list in queries, for example:

```sql
select
   fruit
from
   {{ ref( 'other_model' ) }}
where
   fruit in {{ list_of_fruits() }}
```

We can then create a macro, for example:

```sql
{% macro list_of_fruits() %}
    
    {% set fruits = # how to read the list of the fruits from the file? %}
    fruit IN ({{ fruits | join(', ') }})

{% endmacro %}
```

How can we achieve this in DBT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a seed file:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/seeds

Once you load the seed file with `dbt seed` you could then use:

```
select
   fruit
from
   {{ ref( 'other_model' ) }}
where
   fruit in (select fruit from {{ ref('seed_model_here') }} )
```